# text autofill program in python with list indice problems

Tags: python

```
def printBoard(board):
    for i in board:
        for j in i:
            print(j, end="")
        print()

def autofill(board,square):
    if board[int(square[0])][int(square[1])] == "X":
        pass
    else:
        board[int(square[0])][int(square[1])] = "X"
        if int(square[0]) + 1 < len(board[int(square[0])]):
            squareList2 = [(int(square[0]) + 1), (int(square[1]))]
            board = autofill(board,squareList2)
        if int(square[0]) - 1 >= 0:
            squareList3 = [(int(square[0]) - 1),(int(square[1]))]
            board = autofill(board, squareList3)
        if int(square[1]) + 1 < len(board[int(square[1])]):
            squareList4 = [(int(square[0])),(int(square[1]) + 1)]
            board = autofill(board, squareList4)
        if int(square[1]) - 1 >= 0:
            squareList5 = [(int(square[0])),(int(square[1] - 1))]
            board = autofill(board, squareList5)
    return board

def main():
    board = []
    filename = input("Please enter a filename: ")
    file = open(filename,"r")
    for line in file:
        row = []
        for item in line:
            if item != "\n":
                row.append(item)
        board.append(row)
    printBoard(board)
    square1 = ""
    while square1 != "q":
        square1 = input("Please enter a square to fill, or q to exit: ")
        if square1 != "q":
            squareList = square1.split(", ")
            squareList[0] = int(squareList[0]) - 1
            squareList[1] = int(squareList[1]) - 1
            board = autofill(board, squareList)
            print(len(board))
            print(len(board[0]))
            printBoard(board)

main()
```

Output

```
Please enter a filename: input.txt
OOOOOOXOOOO
OOOOOXOOOOO
OOOOXOOOOOO
XXOOXOOOOOO
XXXXOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOO
Please enter a square to fill, or q to exit: 1, 1
6
11
XXXXXXXOOOO
XXXXXXOOOOO
XXXXXOOOOOO
XXXXXOOOOOO
XXXXOOOOOOO
OOOOOOOOOOO
Please enter a square to fill, or q to exit: 6, 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "proj2.py", line 49, in <module>
    main()
  File "proj2.py", line 44, in main
    board = autofill(board, squareList)
  File "proj2.py", line 14, in autofill
    board = autofill(board,squareList2)
  File "proj2.py", line 8, in autofill
    if board[int(square[0])][int(square[1])] == "X":
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Instead of getting the error, 6, 1 should have made everything an X.

This is a school homework assignment and the rules are "Autofill takes a given square, and if it is an X does nothing. If the square has an O in it, it changes the O to an X and autofills the square above, below, to the left, and to the right. An example run of the program:"

The text file isn't important, its just how the 2d list board was imported.

I don't understand why I get these list indice problems though. I printed out the row length and column length and they seem to be correct.

Comment: The first step is to put the problematic statement in a `try` block, then follow it with an `except` block with something like `print(len(board)-1, int(square[0]), len(board[int(square[0])])-1, int(square[1]))`. This will tell you what indices it can use and what indices it's trying to use.

Comment: Hint... Feeding "6, 1" to `input("...")` does not return the string `"6, 1"` as you seem to expect, but the tuple `(6, 1)`... Assuming this is Python 2.x, anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem was that you were checking whether it was okay to increment `square[0]` by checking the length of `board[int(square[0])]` rather than simply the length of `board`. Same for `square[1]` - you were checking `board[int(square[0])][int(square[1])]` rather than simply `board[int(square[0])]`. In effect, you were checking one level too deep.

I've fixed the problem and significantly cleaned up your code (I couldn't fix it until I had cleaned it up). Changes outside of `autofill()` are marked with `# note change`.

```
def printBoard(board):
    for i in board:
        print(*i, sep='') # note change

def autofill(board,x, y):
    if board[x][y] != "X":
        board[x][y] = "X"
        if x + 1 < len(board):
            board = autofill(board,x+1, y)
        if x - 1 >= 0:
            board = autofill(board, x-1, y)
        if y + 1 < len(board[x]):
            board = autofill(board, x, y+1)
        if y - 1 >= 0:
            board = autofill(board, x, y-1)
    return board

def main():
    filename = input("Please enter a filename: ")
    with open(filename, 'r') as f: # note change
        board = [list(line.strip()) for line in f] # note change
    printBoard(board)
    square1 = ""
    while square1 != "q":
        square1 = input("Please enter a square to fill, or q to exit: ")
        if square1 != "q":
            x, y = map(int, square1.split(",")) # note change
            x-=1 # note change
            y-=1 # note change
            board = autofill(board, x, y) # note change
            printBoard(board)
main()
```